# Subquery in a JOIN

Tags: sql, ms-access

Two tables in MS Access - clients and visits - at a food pantry where we track our clients, when they come, etc.
I'd like to know which clients *used to* come, but haven't been recently; for example, they came to pantry some time in 2019 but haven't been since.
I got the code below from a friend who does SQLPlus all the time, but doesn't know Access.
Code below gives me "Syntax error in JOIN operation".
Thanks for any help in getting this done in Access.

```
SELECT tbl_Clients.[First Name], tbl_Clients.[Last Name], tbl_Visits.[Session Date]
FROM tbl_Visits
INNER JOIN 
  (select tbl_Visits.[Client ID], Last(tbl_Visits.[Session Date]) as LastVisit 
     from tbl_Visits 
         group by tbl_Visits.[Session Date]) V1 
     ON (tbl_Visits.[Client ID] = tbl_Clients.[Client ID])
WHERE LastVisit between [Start date (mm/dd/yy)] and [End date (mm/dd/yy)];
```

Comment: This is not a code writers site... show us all you have tried and come with a specific question. not, please write this for me...

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation:

```
select [Client ID], max([Session Date])
from tbl_visits
group by [Client ID]
having year(max([Session Date])) = 2019;
```

If you need more information about the clients, you can use this as a subquery with `INNER JOIN`, `IN`, or `EXISTS`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  This got me essentially what I wanted, and I tweaked the HAVING to my specifications.

Answer (score 0):

Your immediate error is referencing a table, `tblClients`, in the `ON` clause that is not explicitly declared in `FROM` or `JOIN`. Also, you do not incorporate the subquery aliased, `V1`, in the `ON` clause.

Additionally, you have an invalid aggregation query where you `GROUP BY` the session date (the very column being aggregated) but `SELECT` client field. Instead, `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` the client field. Also it is better to use the `MAX` and not the `LAST` aggregate for dates.

Altogether, consider below adjustment that joins clients, visits, and subquery together to return each client's visits but only for those clients whose latest visit falls within specified time range. Results are then sorted in descending order by session date. Below uses shorter table aliases.

```
SELECT c.[First Name]
     , c.[Last Name]
     , v.[Session Date]
 
FROM (tbl_Clients c
INNER JOIN tbl_Visits v
  ON v.[Client ID] = c.[Client ID])

INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT sub_v.[Client ID]
           , MAX(sub_v.[Session Date]) AS LastVisit 
     FROM tbl_Visits sub_v
     GROUP BY sub_v.[Client ID]
    ) max_dt 
  ON c.[Client ID] = max_dt.[Client ID]

WHERE max_dt.LastVisit BETWEEN [Start date (mm/dd/yy)] 
                           AND [End date (mm/dd/yy)]

ORDER BY c.[First Name], v.[Session Date] DESC;
```

---

Should you need only client level aggregation, then avoid the subquery and aggregate on join of clients and visits tables with `HAVING` to filter based on aggregate value.

```sql
SELECT  c.[First Name]
      , c.[Last Name]
      , MAX(v.[Session Date]) AS LastVisit 

FROM tbl_Visits v
INNER JOIN tbl_Clients c
   ON c.[Client ID] = v.[Client ID]
GROUP BY  c.[First Name]
        , c.[Last Name]
        , c.[Client ID]

HAVING MAX(v.[Session Date]) BETWEEN [Start date (mm/dd/yy)] 
                                 AND [End date (mm/dd/yy)];
```

Comment: Your code selects every Visits row when I want only the MAX.  But thanks for the quick and elegant reply.